# Inno Setup - Fully resolve an environment variable that contains another variable

Tags: global-variables, environment-variables, inno-setup

**Edit** - this issue appears to be Windows 7 and Vista due to a bug [(see here - Same issue reported)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6cb3e0f5-f401-4c73-a756-666565a4d762/expanding-environment-variables-in-windows-7-and-missing-properties-under-right-click-computer-?forum=w7itproinstall)

**Edit2** - I might be running into a similar issue users wee with PATH (I am not using PATH but same result - [Unanswered question with similar issues](https://superuser.com/questions/27826/why-cant-windows-handle-an-environment-variable-in-path/27828#27828%22An%20unanswered%20post%20on%20a%20similar%20issue.%22)

I have an Inno Setup script that uses an environment variable to locate a folder and delete the contents. When I try to expand the variable without elevated privileges  I get this:

TEST_USER=%APPDATA%\PROG\USER_DATA  (this is set in Windows)

If I run this as Admin (or change privileges to admin) I see:

TESTUSER=c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\PROG\USER_DATA

Googling %APPDATA% issues shows others have this issue, usually they hit this when used in PATH, something to do with the path not being set before it is requested.

I was hoping to avoid a complex routine of checking with pos if the return value contains %appdata%. But I think that might be my only solution.

[cmd.exe - Example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYmif.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InnoSetup, expand environment variable (taken from registry value using {reg:...} )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024362/innosetup-expand-environment-variable-taken-from-registry-value-using-reg)

Comment: + It's just nonsense that the behavior is different when running as Administrator and when not. You must have the variable set differently for Administrator and a regular user.

Comment: It is not nonsense. This is a variable that has never been able to be resolved and this is a differnet project than the last question. It is for a similar purpose but different usecase and program. 

My previous project dealt with variables assigned by an already running application. This is variable I have no control over they are already set.

I employed the same debugging method to make a PRINT of the found variable. And it is EXACTLY as I have shown in my question. I appreciate the previous help but if is offensive to say it is nonsense when this is my exact result.

Comment: I am getting closer to solving this with a more complex work around and finding when %appdata% is employed and replacing it. I was hoping maybe something like ExpandConstantEx would do it but I have not found an example yet.

OK FOR PROOF:
Please set a fake variable and use %appdata% in the value. Now open a regular command window and try to change dir to your new variable cd %NEWVAR% and it will fail!...now run the cmd as administrator and try again and now it will succeed.

Comment: I have of course tested it before posting. With a user variable `TEST_USER=%APPDATA%\PROG\USER_DATA` and your `ExpandConstant('{%TEST_USER}\*')` expression, I'm getting `C:\Users\martin\AppData\Roaming\PROG\USER_DATA\*` no mater what. The same with command prompt: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rYDqQ.png

Comment: And if you want to expand the variable explicitly, use the `ExpandEnvVars` function in the linked answer.

Comment: No change with system variables: http://i.stack.imgur.com/47hYF.png

Comment: But I've helped you already. The link in my very first comment has a code to expand variables in a string. Did you try it?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the problem on Win7. But it still works. Show us a screenshot of the "Environment variables" dialog. Also show us a screenshot of `regedit` for key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` showing how the variable is set. I have this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5sBRE.png How do you run the command prompt? I cannot get it to say "Windows Command Processor" in the title. Your screenshots shows path `C:\Windows\System32`, what suggests an elevated prompt. But you claimed that it works for you with Admin account. Is it elevated prompt?

Comment: **Why** it does not fit your need? Why are you trying to do it the hard way with `Pos`, if there's a ready made function? I'm not accusing you of anything. I'm just trying to reproduce the problem you are reporting. If you do not like that, ok, I'm leaving.

Comment: I do appreciate your assistance, when I started I thought it was an inno setup or pascal issue, then I found the same issue manually with cmd.exe method but thought scripting could force the expansion with some method I did not know. Only way is privileges=admin which causes other issues. When you proved you did not have the same issue (I thought this was a common problem with appdata) that led me to check why did I have this and it is a known windows issue. I posted links. So that only leaves deal with the issue that is left by conditions. I actually learned more that way so not all bad :)

Comment: You still did not explain why the `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` WinAPI function and its `ExpandEnvVars` wrapper in the answer to [InnoSetup, expand environment variable (taken from registry value using {reg:…} )](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32024923/850848) is not a solution for you. You seem to keep rejecting it based on a word "registry" in the question title. But that only refers to the source of the un-expanded string. But the source of the string has nothing to do with actually expanding it.

Comment: Hmm I was assuming it delves into the value of the registry. You feel this will expand the current variable? I have looked and chunks of code are over my head. I do small amounts of coding and was never that familiar with pascal. My last few scripts have pushed me deeper but it still takes me making 20/30 mistakes to get 1 good result. I don't think I know how to rewrite that answer to even test it.

Comment: Just copy the `Code` section (except for the `GetDefaultDirName` function, which you do not need) to the front of your `Code` section. And then use it like `test_user := ExpandEnvVars(ExpandConstant('{%TEST_USER}'));`

Comment: OK it was the RegQueryStringValue part and the const  RegKeyVS2015 = 'Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0'; lines that caused me concern. I have now removed them. 
I have tested it with a msg popup and the TEST_USER is being resolved now. IT WORKS!. I did not know I could strip those parts out I thought it was for checking registry query.

OK should I delete everything as I guess this can qualify as a duplicate question? Or should I update my answer with the final version I used and reference TLama's answer I am not sure how to wrap this?

Comment: Found 1 issue I do not understand? it breaks msgbox so possibly no ability to use result with any additions?

`test_user_new := ExpandEnvVars(ExpandConstant('{%TEST_USER}'));

       MsgBox('The Current Folder Found :' + #13#10#13#10 + test_user +  #13#10#13#10 + 'Do you wish to still proceed?', mbInformation, MB_YESNO)`

Never shows extra line after test_user

`test_user_old := (ExpandConstant('{%TEST_USER}')); 

    MsgBox('The Current Folder Found :' + #13#10#13#10 + test_user2 +  #13#10#13#10 + 'Do you wish to still proceed?', mbInformation, MB_YESNO)`

Works as normal.

Comment: True. Use the [answer by @Tobias81](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34069631/850848), which is the correct one (upvote it, so that it gets more attention). I think you can keep your answer (and accept it), but maybe add a link to the the other question to the front, as a reference to a more universal solution.

Comment: *cannot be used with any other string* - Give us an example. + Sure you can turn it to a function. But why? Just make the `folder_to_delete` (or `folder_to_find` - you have that inconsistent in you answer) a global variable and use it everywhere. If I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: That's still the same issue as you have [reported above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623368/inno-setup-fully-resolve-an-environment-variable-that-contains-another-variabl?noredirect=1#comment62814452_37623368), isn't it? It should be fixed by using the [answer by @Tobias81](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34069631/850848) as I have suggested already.

Comment: OK, what is `resolved_result`? Is it `resolved_result := ExpandEnvVars(ExpandConstant('{%TEST_USER}'))`?

Comment: When I used code `resolved_result := ExpandEnvVars(ExpandConstant('{%TEST_USER}')); deltree(resolved_result+'\somefolder', False, True, True);` and the `TEST_USER=%APPDATA%\PROG\USER_DATA`, the `C:\Users\martin\AppData\Roaming\PROG\USER_DATA\somefolder` is deleted as expected and the `C:\Users\martin\AppData\Roaming\PROG\USER_DATA` is kept intact. To the concatenation works. What part do you have different?

Comment: Sure it does work: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fzBHH.png

Comment: No the `const` is not an issue. What version of Inno Setup? Is it Ansi or Unicode? I have the latest 5.5.9 Unicode.

Comment: And do you have the Unicode version? + Yes, the `#0` is the problem.

Comment: First, you wrote that `resolved_result = 'Windows_NT'#0't'`, but then that there's no trailing `'`. I can get the behavior without the trailing `'` with @TLama's code, but not with @Tobias81's code. I cannot get the `#0`. Where do you debug the script? In Inno Setup compiler or Inno Script Studio? (I cannot get the Inno Script studio to display the values at all). I always compile (on command-line). I do not use GUI myself. Can you append your code bsed @Tobias81's code to your answer? Can you link your (non-working) compiled test-installer?

Comment: Np. Yes, please cleanup the comments.

Comment: Tested with [@Tobias81](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34069631/6383448) (note do not use the code from top of that answer it causes extra issues as noted in the comments). Working great resolves the variables as any user now. Learning pos was useful but using this code is cleaner and simpler.

Comment: Please upvote his answer. You should have privilege to do so now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my answer to make it work. However, please check the answer from [@Tobias81](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34069631/850848) to [InnoSetup, expand environment variable (taken from registry value using {reg:...} )](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32024362/850848) that works and offers a more generic solution.

---

I am making multiple modules first then combining later to making 1 executable with multiple components so a user can select an action. Due to this I need to check the current value of a variable not the registry value.  Plus the registry still returns `%APPDATA%` as my screen shot.

So my answer was to just hunt for the appearance of `%APPDATA%` and deal with it.

Here is my debugging routine. Now I can find it and deal with it allowing me to find the value no matter if it was set by the parent or only set in windows.

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  test_user: string;
  app_user: string;
  folder_to_find: string;
begin
  test_user := (ExpandConstant('{%TEST_USER}'));
  app_user := (ExpandConstant('{%APPPDATA}'));
  if (test_user <> '') AND (Pos(Uppercase('%APPDATA%'), Uppercase(test_user))=0) then
  begin
    folder_to_find := test_user;
    MsgBox('Folder found : ' + folder_to_find + ' APPDATA STRING WAS NOT DETECTED', mbInformation, MB_OK)
  end
    else
  if (test_user <> '') AND (Pos(Uppercase('%APPDATA%'), Uppercase(test_user))=1) then 
  begin
    StringChangeEx(test_user, '%APPDATA%', '', True);
    folder_to_find := app_user + test_user;
    MsgBox('Folder found : ' + folder_to_find + ' APPDATA STRING WAS DETECTED & REMOVED!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end
    else
  begin
    MsgBox('The TEST_USER Environment is not set' + #13#10#13#10 + 'This process will now exit!',mbInformation, MB_OK)
    Abort;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This was my answer to make it work however. PLEASE check the answer from [@Tobias81](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024362/innosetup-expand-environment-variable-taken-from-registry-value-using-reg/34069631#34069631) that works and removes problems with code posted above it in that same thread. I have up voted it as it works great.